# How to make the video translucent, not the background but the actual video(content)

Tags: java, android

This is written by sinch in Android Studio.
I have 2 views with videos in it. I want to make the top video translucent, so the video below can be seen as well. I tried changing the alpha but did not work. Code is as below:

```
private void addVideoViews() {
        if (mVideoViewsAdded || getSinchServiceInterface() == null) {
            return; //early
    }

    final VideoController vc = getSinchServiceInterface().getVideoController();
    if (vc != null) {
        RelativeLayout localView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.localVideo);
        localView.addView(vc.getLocalView());
        localView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                vc.toggleCaptureDevicePosition();
            }
        });

        LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.remoteVideo);
        view.addView(vc.getRemoteView());
        mVideoViewsAdded = true;
```

Comment: have you tried changing `alpha` of the `vc` or even of the whole `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   final VideoController vc = getSinchServiceInterface().getVideoController();
   if (vc != null) {
     RelativeLayout localView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.localVideo);
     View lView = vc.getLocalView();
     lView.getBackground().setAlpha(128);
     localView.addView(lView);
     localView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            vc.toggleCaptureDevicePosition();
        }
    });

    LinearLayout view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.remoteVideo);
    View rView = vc.getRemoteView();
    rView.getBackground().setAlpha(128);
    view.addView(rView);
    mVideoViewsAdded = true;
```

However, I'm not sure if the library that you are using supports functionality that you want.